# Running nginx infront of a unicorn or gunicorn under Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, unicorn, gunicorn, amazon-elb

I have a very simple question. Nginx does reverse proxy buffering for HTTP servers like Gunicorn and Unicorn. However if I have a Elastic Load Balancer (offered by Amazon Web Services also known as -- ELB) is there any point in running nginx in front of my app server?

```
 Request----> ELB -------> NGINX-------> UNICORN/GUNICORN HTTP SERVER
```

Answer (score 7):

In a word: yes.  Amazon's ELB service is wonderful, but it is solely a load balancer.  Running nginx on your own server gives you a locus of control and a place to do rewrites, redirects, compression, header munging, caching, and more.  Furthermore it allows you to serve static files in the fastest possible way, rather than using a slot on your more heavyweight appserver.

Comment: what if I'm not serving any static content at all and I'm only sending json back and forth?

Comment: You can make the call yourself, but from where I sit that still leaves compression and caching as potential benefits.  Also I forgot to mention better policy tools for keepalives.  e if you expose your fat servers directly to the 'net, you'll have a harder time dealing with DOS attacks of various sorts.  For your use case it sounds like there may not be any immediate benefit, but down the road you may see one.

Comment: What i just found is that if i point ELB directly at Gunicorn with all direct settings, it does not work properly at all, because Gunicorn does not do keep-alives, and ELB seems to demand it.